# Intellisense for angular.js does not work in a javascript file

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 which supports Intellisense for Angular.js. Intellisense does indeed work when I create an Angular.js module within a script tag in a HTML5 file. However, when I attempt to create the same module in a javascript file I get no Intellisense. I'm a bit baffled as to why this is the case.

**Intellisense working in HTML file:**

[image: Angular.js Intellisense in HTML file]

**No Intellisense in blank javascript file:**

[image: No Intellisense in javascript file]

I do not have Resharper installed in VS2013. Thanks in advance for your time and any advice!

Comment: See if my answer here can help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830266/angularjs-intellisense-not-working-on-visual-studio-2015/31615630#31615630

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The javascript file needs a reference to angular js so it know what you're talking about.  It looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="ScriptFile1.js" />
```

See here for more info  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Sorry about the slow accept.

Answer (score 6):

Reference angular.js file on top of your JavaScript file like this:

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/angular.min.js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a the uncompressed js file in your project. Visual Studio cannot read the intellisense from the minified js file

Answer (score 0):

If you develop NodeJs project, make sure you select right property for js file. "Build Action" should be equal to "Content", otherwise intellisense will not work

[Properties for js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbhJ5.png)