# Getting angular documentation (intellisense) when writing Javascript?

Tags: angularjs, intellisense

Ok so I've read [Intellisense for angular.js does not work in a javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295465/intellisense-for-angular-js-does-not-work-in-a-javascript-file) and googled and even installed https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AngularJS/ (I have resharper).

I do have basic code completion of angular stuff when writing js, and the above extension gives nice code completion for html directives in the html files. However I'm wondering if there's anything that could give me real documentation on the fly, like intellisense does for C#, something that pops up and goes something like:

".directive - this method is used to define custom directives.
  Parameters: directive name - a normalized string..."

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded until getting intellisense but not documentation.

IN VS 2015 open Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> Intellisense -> References.

Under the Add section open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\JavaScript\References" and add "angular.intellisense.js".

If you don't have "angular.intellisense.js"  see the below articles to get the file.

http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2015/02/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio.html

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/02/05/using-angularjs-in-visual-studio-2013/