# Angular Intellisense VS2015 RTM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Reading the release notes, [Angular is supposed to have better intellisense in VS2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx).

After Just upgrading VS2015 to VS2015RTM I appear to be missing intellisense in script blocks on Razor views, and in js files.

After "file new web application (ASP.NET 5 Preview Template)", I've added a dependency to Angular via the bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-touch-carousel": "0.8.0",
    "hammer.js": "2.0.4",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "jquery-validation": "1.11.1",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.2",
    "angular": "~1.4.3"
  }
}
```

and i can see the TaskRunner has successfully run the gulp task and generated a lib\angular folder.

[image]

I've referenced angular in the layout but i get no intellisense.

[image]

Do I need to install something or is the manual copy of that [intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830266/angularjs-intellisense-not-working-on-visual-studio-2015) file required? If so it doesn't feel like that's a vs2015 intellisense enhancement, as I assume it could also be done on VS2013?

**UPDATE**

I've duplicated the advice from the attached Link and put the angular.intellisense.js file in both the

> Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   **12.0**\JavaScript\References

folder
and the

> Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   **14.0**\JavaScript\References

folder

I now have working Intellisense in VS2013 but not in VS2015.

Also tried adding

```
/// <reference path="lib/angular/angular.js />
```

to the _references.js file but still no angular intellisense.

Comment: Try typing `ng-`, stuff gets grouped to make it "easier" to find.

Comment: (in a script tag) If i type angular. I should surely get intellisense for angular.module etc?  Additionally if i do type ng-  i can only see templates to insert a controller,directive or service no actual intellisense.

Comment: I think its a major problem and have raised it as a issue.. Jim bledsoe one of the guys who helped create it is working with me to flesh this out ..If you have a simple "hello world" app "it works" i.e as in a single html page with script in the header ... 2015 RTM basically stops working as soon as you start creting views/controllers/directives etc .. If there is some way to make it work I would lve to know :( .. Heres a link to git issue [link]https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/issues/26

Answer (score 5):

I installed the 'AngularJS.Intellisense' NuGet package and it worked for me.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/

Strange why Microsoft did not added it by default in the RTM version.

**UPDATE** -

I found the solution - I talked with one of Microsoft's engineers about the issue and he helped me to fix the issue..

All what you need to do is to add a new JS file to your wwwroot folder called: **_references.js**

and then in it you should add a reference to all the JS files you are working with in the following format:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />

/// <reference path="js/main.js" />
/// <reference path="lib/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="lib/angular/index.js" />
```

or in the Solution Explorer - right click on the _references.js file and click on: **Auto-sync JavaScript References** and click on ** Update JavaScript References** (which will automatically add all the references in your solution:

[image: _references.js file]

After that you will get angular support in the JavaScripts as:
[image: angular support]

BTW - it works with all the types of the web projects - just add the **_references.js** file and add a reference to all the JavaScript libraries/files you are using and it will work.

I hope it will help you as well :).

Comment: This doesn't work for me in VS2015 RTM. It looks like this was designed for VS2013. https://github.com/cicorias/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/

Comment: It works great for me on VS2015 RTM. Try to install it in the project you are working on and try to close the project and reopen it.

Comment: Still no luck despite closing vs and restarting etc.

Comment: If you file,new  asp.net5 web application(using the preview template) you automatically get a _references.js. After adding those lines there is no intellisense still and no update js references option on right click. However if i create a new 46 project there is.

Comment: It works great for me.. Check the path of the angular.js file.. Check where the angular.js file is located and add it to the _references.js file with the full path.

Comment: yeah these were the very first things i did. I do get an error saying the referenced file 'lib/angular/angular.js' is not found but the path is correct, and no error for the index.js'. Also no right click option

Comment: just got it working, its quite buggy the experience, file new project, replicated adding angular to bower, right click on _references and no update option, add the lines to _references by typing, save and no intellisense, right click and the update option is present now, choose update and the lines are removed from _references. however drag the js files into the _references and it creates the lines and those lines do work. right clicking and updating does get them removed each time however

Comment: can you replicate my issues if you manually add the references, or right click and update references? Any idea where i can log this it seems like a tooling bug

Comment: I had the same issue.. Where the Update removed the references for the angular.js file. But after adding them manually it works.. It takes few seconds until it will work. By the way, make sure you have the '/// <autosync enabled="true" />. Try starting a new project and install the angular using bower and after that create the _references.js and after that create a new JavaScript file and check if it works.

Comment: I used the template so I had all those defaults by default. and manually typing didn't work for me, it had to be added from dragging and dropping the js files into the references file so it auto added the references. Definitely a little buggy experience.

Comment: that doesnt work for anything more complex than a very basic implememnattion and then it MAY work only for the angular object ..$http $location etc etc dont work