# Visual Studio 2015 Javascript / AngularJs not functioning correctly

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, javascript-intellisense

My intellisense is not working in visual studio 2015.

I have a _references.js file under the scripts directory that points to all my angular files.

I have angular.intellisense.js in my options set up under Implicit (Web)

My project is a MVC/WebAPI project created in Visual Studio 2013.

Could this be the issue because I didn't create the project in VS2015?

My angular structure.
-app
   --admin
  --components (all angular and js files for site go here)
  --core
  --dashboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS intellisense not working on Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29830266/11683)

Comment: Yes it is I will put my comments on the other question.

Comment: I am one of the people working on the feature for MSFT. Would it be possible for you to provide a brief repro project for me to take a look at? Thanks,
Alex Gavrilov

Comment: Hi Alex, Here's the repo for the sample project. https://github.com/GregLarden/VS2015-Angular-Intellisense-Test