# How to set up AngularJS 1 typing in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I'm having difficulties getting Angular typings to work on VS Code. 
Could someone give a detailed step-by-step guide on how to do so?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. *"Difficulties"* is not a clear problem statement, and *"a detailed step-by-step guide"* isn't an appropriate thing to ask for.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I don't really know a way to describe my issue and have been trying to get it to work for the past 3 hours with no success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

are talking about IntelliSense ?

There is a post about it (read de answer 3): [No IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015 for AngularJS TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288505/no-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2015-for-angularjs-typescript)

STEPs:

I've installed tsd globally using NPM:

**npm install -g tsd**

then using a command prompt in the root folder of my solution, I've installed the AngularJS type definitions by entering the following command:

**tsd install angular**

It automatically downloaded the type definitions into a folder named "typings/angularjs" and IntelliSense started working as intended.