# Angular Intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I've done everything I thought possible to make the Angular JS Intellisense works in VS 2015 Community, with no success.
Including this http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs

_reference.js, visual studio references (Web Implicit)... I tried them both!

Am I missing something or it's impossible to have the Angular Intellisense in VS 2015 Community?

Thanks for our help...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAcDb.png)

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830266/angularjs-intellisense-not-working-on-visual-studio-2015

Comment: thanks for your reply Comoss. Yeah, I've follow the instructions in this post you've sent, but the Intellisense kinda half-works. Unfortunately some classes and properties works and others don't. The case shown in the screenshot still doesn't work =/