# Detect Typing errors in AngularJS tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resharper

I'm new at AngularJS, and there is one things which bothers me. It seems like there is no help at all, neither from the editor (I'm using Visual Studio with Resharper), nor from the browser / runtime components, when it comes to detecting typing / syntax errors within angularJS directives such as "**ng-repeat**". for example, if I type

`<tr ng-repeat="f in m.myAray" />` (note the missing "r")

instead of

`<tr ng-repeat="f in m.myArray" />`

I just see no table rows. I'm completely on my own finding the cause by closely looking at the source. I will get no clue in the browser console window or wherever. Even R# does not warn me.

I fear that I am being thrown back into the ancient age of programming using VB6 without "option explicit", where finding causes of errors like this have been easily taken up half a day, just because someone made a spelling error in a variable name.

Do I overlook something obvious? Or am I just a spoiled programmer who is being used to rely on intellisense and R# for every problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be supported by Resharper in the (hopefully near) future. 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/angular_support.gif.gif?file=74-377248&c=true&rw=853&rh=476&u=1484832480398

see feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462599

we all look forward to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**For Intellisense**,
one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830266/angularjs-intellisense-not-working-on-visual-studio-2015) should be able to help you.

Comment: I do have intellisense working within <script> tags. but my question was about intellisense in AngularJS tags such as "ng-repeat".

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually possible. If you look at it for what it is, `ng-repeat` is only an HTML attribute, (albeit one that the angular engine recognizes). In that sense though, such declarations are not actually angular at all, they can't _see_ the controller scope or any variables declared on it, it's the other way round, angular _uses_ them to manipulate the DOM (if that makes sense!?).

Comment: My problem is actually: If the ng-repeat directive (or any other angular directive) does not work as expected, i.e. displays nothing, how I am supposed to find the error? It doesn't seem possible to debug the ng-repeat "expression" in the browser, i.e. put a breakpoint or step-through. So the only way is to look closely at the source text and try to find the cause? in real-life, I sometimes will have much more complicated expressions there than just a variable name, so I guess I will spend a lot of time tracking down "trivial" errors such as this.

Answer (score 0):

**For Debugging**, [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) allows you to look at the scopes used in your angular application.

Sure, it's not going to flag up any syntax errors or misnamed variables, but it will at least allow you to confirm which variables the directive's scope can see and use. From that you should be able to determine that `myAray` doesn't exist on the scope and that it should be renamed to `myArray` (as in your example).

Comment: I'm aware of this extension, but relying on this is far from a "developer-friendly" way as I would imagine it. 
I just created a suggestion for the R# folks to support intellisense within AngularJS directives (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462599). Perhaps they make something out of it. Feel free to upvote! :-)

Comment: I've voted for it, it would certainly be useful. Good Luck!

Comment: seems like the JetBrains guys are already on it... looks promising: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/angular_support.gif.gif?file=74-377248&c=true&rw=853&rh=476&u=1484832480398